# Using hyphens in email address

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-7

I am trying to send emails in Laravel only in won't accept hyphens in the email address. It works fine with email addresses without hyphens.

This works:

```
Mail::raw('Text', function ($message){
    $message->to('mail@example.com');
});
```

This does not work and results in the following error:

```
Mail::raw('Text', function ($message){
    $message->to('mail@exam-ple.com');
});
```

> Swift_TransportException
>   Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients"

So, I am a little confused as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using any Mail API to send the emails?

Comment: I would wager that you're attempting to send mail through a server that isn't set up to relay mail for just _any_ domain. Contact your mail server's admin.

Comment: @Sammitch I can send mail to any email address but not if it contains a hyphen

Comment: Then I'll revise my response to simply "contact your mail server's admin", because it's the mail server that's rejecting it.